# ExitException: Unable to load resource: http://[host]:[port]/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndforms.jar

Tags: java, oracle

This error only occurs in one user when the user open a form in oracle application. The user already tried TLS options, direct connection, delete temporary files but it does not work

```
`General Exception
Name: oracle.apps.fnd.formsClient.jnlp.Fnd...
ExitException: Unable to load resource: http://[host]:[port]/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndforms.jar


ExitException[3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http//[host]:     [port]/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndforms.jar

at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.load.JarFiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

No such an error prompts

Comment: If it only occurs for a single user, my guess is that user cannot access `[host]:[port]`. Maybe there is a firewall and `[port]` is not open to him (or her). Maybe a security certificate is missing from the JRE that the user is running the Oracle application with.